# Lecture videos on number theory?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, education, online-resources

I am looking for lecture videos about elementary number theory.

I tried google but I find advanced and usually they are talks and seminars not course lectures.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: (In English and for free, right?)

Comment: Video lectures on number theory seem to be rare, but you could go with cryptography

Comment: @user66081, yes!

Comment: See [UCCS](https://uccs1.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx#folderID=%2229214073-a71b-49bc-b0ee-a9d2017aa828%22&page=0)  or [James Cook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E51GKQ1qorE&list=PLBY4G2o7DhF3dBX7vxpS6b119SyM3S7WJ) lectures or Steven Miller's analysis+number theory lectures (link is in his web page, google it).

Answer (score 2):

I found these by Googling:

- http://www.infocobuild.com/education/learn-through-videos/mathematics/introduction-to-number-theory.html
- https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto
- https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540852971

There's also a similar question over at MathOverFlow, which should have some ideas: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free

**EDIT**: One of the provided links had become broken, but it had the same content as the added third link above (although the book is unfortunately not free).

I have seen/followed none of these courses, so be critical in choosing which one to follow (if any). Good luck!